# ¿Como dibujar una matriz redimensionable en windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Logré dibujar una matriz con el siguiente código en mi `Form1`:

```
    // Create brush.
    Brush mybrush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray);
    // Create pen.
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Draw
        Draw2DArray(sender,e,myPen,mybrush);
    }
```

Método que dibuja la matriz:

```
private void Draw2DArray(object sender, PaintEventArgs e, Pen p, Brush b)
    {
        int row = 2; //rows
        int column = 2;//columns

        int step = 43; //distance between the rows and columns
        int width = 40; //the width of the rectangle
        int height = 40; //the height of the rectangle

        // Create rectangle Matrix.
        Rectangle[,] rectangleMatrix = new Rectangle[row, column];

        // Draw 
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(5 + step * j, 5 + step * i), new Size(width, height));
                rectangleMatrix[i, j] = rect;
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect);                    
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, rect);
            }
        }

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podría hacer que la matriz dibujada sea al tamaño del `Form1` y que sea re-ajustable según su tamaño?

Comment: windows forms no fue pensado para ello(responsive), ademas de que windows form posee pocos recursos para estos casos , te sugiero usar WPF.

Comment: Estás poniendo un ancho y un alto fijos para cada rectángulo. Lo que debes hacer es calcular estos parámetros en función de las dimensiones del Form

Comment: @DiegoAvila lo tomare en cuenta.

Comment: Ok @Pikoh estoy intentando hacerlo, gracias por la orientación.